# Python, where are the data for tips under Plotly from?

Tags: python, plotly

```
import plotly.express as px
tips = px.data.tips()
tips
px.histogram(tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", histfunc="sum", color="smoker")
```

just a few lines and there are already all this data in "tips", I am very confused where do those number coming from? Thanks a lot
tips

```
Out[125]: 
     total_bill   tip     sex smoker   day    time  size
0         16.99  1.01  Female     No   Sun  Dinner     2
1         10.34  1.66    Male     No   Sun  Dinner     3
2         21.01  3.50    Male     No   Sun  Dinner     3
3         23.68  3.31    Male     No   Sun  Dinner     2
4         24.59  3.61  Female     No   Sun  Dinner     4
..          ...   ...     ...    ...   ...     ...   ...
239       29.03  5.92    Male     No   Sat  Dinner     3
240       27.18  2.00  Female    Yes   Sat  Dinner     2
241       22.67  2.00    Male    Yes   Sat  Dinner     2
242       17.82  1.75    Male     No   Sat  Dinner     2
243       18.78  3.00  Female     No  Thur  Dinner     2

[244 rows x 7 columns]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using

```
import plotly.express as px

print(px.data.__file__)
```

you can see path to source code and check it.

Digging in source code I found that on Linux data are in folder

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/plotly/package_data/datasets/
```

as `.csv` files compressed to `.gz` files so `pandas.read_csv()` can read it without problem.
And `tips()` uses `pandas.read_csv()` to read it.

---

You can display other functions in `px.data` which reads datasets using `dir()`

```
import plotly.express as px

for name in dir(px.data):
    if '__' not in name:
        print(name)
```

Result

```
absolute_import
carshare
election
gapminder
iris
tips
wind
```

Probably all of them (except `absolute_import`) are functions which reads some `.gz` file with data.

```
print(px.data.carshare())
print(px.data.election())
print(px.data.gapminder())
print(px.data.iris())
print(px.data.tips())
print(px.data.wind())
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few small dataset you can import from plotly.express.

When you write
 tips = px.data.tips()
It’s import this data